# How to group data from 1-many relation in a single query using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, **recipes**, **recipes_instructions**, **recipes_ingredients**, the first is the main and the rest refers to the *recipe_id* from the **recipes** table.

I wrote the code below to try and get something working, right now it's retrieving all of the data that I want, I'm just not sure how to organize it by it's group, I think *GROUP_CONCAT* is the way to go but just not sure how to go about it.

This is my desired result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Citrus Shortbread Cookies
    [instruction_group] => Array (
        [0] => Divide the dough into 2 equal portions...
        [1] => Preheat an oven to...
        [2] => Remove wax paper, and...
        [3] => Bake in the preheated oven...
    )
    [ingredients_group] => Array (
        [0] => 1 cup (230g) butter
        [1] => 1 teaspoon vanilla extract
        [2] => 2 cups (250g) all-purpose flour
        [3] => Zest of one lime
        [4] => 1/2 cup (65g) icing sugar
    )
)
```

**What I've tried:**

1: This is the closest that I got to what I want, it still has duplicate results and it's retrieving all data from database even from the recipe id that wasn't specified.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725468/33

```
SELECT *
  FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT recipe_id, GROUP_CONCAT(instruction) instruction_group FROM recipe_instructions) 
  as instructionscombined 
  on recipes.id = instructionscombined.recipe_id
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT recipe_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ingredients) ingredient_group FROM recipe_ingredients)
  as ingredientscombined
  on recipes.id = ingredientscombined.recipe_id
WHERE recipes.id = 1
```

2: Duplicate results, all data from table has been returned even from the ones that the recipe id wasn't specified.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725468/39

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(inst.instruction), GROUP_CONCAT(ingr.ingredients) FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN recipe_instructions as inst on recipes.id = inst.recipe_id
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients as ingr on recipes.id = ingr.recipe_id
WHERE recipes.id = 1
```

**EDIT:**
As far as the issue that the queries were returning all the data from the rows was because I wasn't being explicit inside the nested selects.

This has solved the problem but I'm still getting duplicate recipe_id columns

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725468/64

```
SELECT *
  FROM recipes 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT recipe_id, GROUP_CONCAT(instruction) instruction_group 
   FROM recipe_instructions
   WHERE recipe_id = 1
  )
  as instructionscombined 
  on recipes.id = instructionscombined.recipe_id
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT recipe_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ingredients) ingredient_group 
   FROM recipe_ingredients
   WHERE recipe_id = 1
  )
  as ingredientscombined
  on recipes.id = ingredientscombined.recipe_id
WHERE recipes.id = 1
GROUP BY recipes.id
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

So.. what I learned is that mysql has no array capabilities, so what I'm doing for the time being is I'm using the query above, and separating the group_concat by using **GROUP_CONCAT(instructions SEPARATOR \'__\')** (I had to escape the ' since I'm using php), and then running a while loop and exploding the group.

Comment: You left out the ```GROUP BY``` clause

Comment: @SloanThrasher I was testing but no luck.

Comment: I think the design is flawed. Unit and quantity need their own columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.instruction ORDER BY b.instruction_id) as `instructions`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.ingredients ORDER BY c.ingredient_id) as `ingredients`
FROM recipes a
JOIN recipe_instructions b
ON a.id = b.recipe_id
JOIN recipe_ingredients c
ON a.id = c.recipe_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.title
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725468/69/0) with this query.

Comment: @Johnson: If this works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: I didn't even get a notification for this comment, I did see the answer though. It's perfect, I learned A LOT from this, and I mean a lot. Thank you. I do have another question if you're able to help me when you have some time, I'll tag you just in case. :)

Comment: Glad it helped, Even better if you learned from it! That's how I have learned (and continue to learn). Feel free to PM me.